# Connecting to the JMX Agent Programmatically in Java 9

Tags: java, jmx, java-9, attach-api

I need to connect to JMX agent programmatically using Attach API (loading agent at runtime if necessary) as shown in example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.htm#JSMGM-GUID-20C7215D-ED29-4939-B026-FAA01EC65765). This worked fine in Java 8 but doesn't work in Java 9 since there is no management-agent.jar in the lib folder anymore:

```
String agent = vm.getSystemProperties().getProperty("java.home") +
   File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "management-agent.jar";
```

Could you please advice what is the right way to do that in Java 9?

Thanks in advance,
Vadim

Comment: the document you linked needs to be updates it seems, the jar is no more a part of lib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, management-agent.jar has been removed (see [release note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-removed-features-3745614.html#JDK-8043939)). If you looking to start the management agent then look at the new startManagementAgent and startLocalManagementAgent methods in com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.

The "Setting Up Monitoring and Management Programmatically" section in the JDK 9 docs needs to be updated.